Bike turning angle "through what angle". Wordtrick?
See image for the stated problem
Essentially if you ride a bike starting from A going A-B-C-A, in a right sided triangle A-B-C where the 90 degree turn is at the B corner. "Through what angle does your bike turn at C". The answer is stated as 135, is this only a word trick? That to turn a bike you cannot do a sharp 45-degree turn, or am I missing something?


Hi, welcome. Please don't link to pictures of text. Just type out the problem so answerers can see it.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The turn angle is measured with respect to the forward direction of the bike. This makes sense because if you go straight on your bike, you are not turning at all, so your turn should be 0 degrees.  If you make a slight right turn, then your turn is at some small angle. If you make a normal right turn, your turn is 90 degrees.  When you make a sharp turn as you are describing, the turn is more than 90 degrees.  It is a right turn plus an additional 45 degrees, so the turn is 135 degrees.

"The turn angle is measured with respect to the forward direction of the bike". - Thank you for this clarification and explanation. It now makes perfect sense !
